# Using TextField to search from a txt file xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to make a simple iphone program that will allow me to search a keyword when entered into a textfield and then search for it by clicking a rect button. I have searched the site and there is nothing that relates to my current situation. to reiterate, I have a textfield where I would like to enter some text and search for it by clicking a rect button. I have the information i want to search for in a txt file. What is the appropriate way to to go about doing this in xcode for iphone. I appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by search? Will your app just check if it occurs in the file? Will it find all occurrences? Print the line it occurs on?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, You are trying to find a user defined phrase in a text file.

What you should do is read the file to an NSString, and then search the string for the user defined string.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html

Googled it quickly and found an example (Not written by me!):

```
NSString *searchFor = @"home";
NSRange range;
for (NSString *string in stringList)
{
    range = [word rangeOfString:searchFor];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
      NSLog (@"Yay! '%@' found in '%@'.", searchFor, string);
    }
}
```

If I missunderstood you, please update your question so it is better understandable.

Comment: Is this searching in App bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)searchWord:(NSString *)wordToBeSearched{
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wordFile"
                                             ofType:@"txt"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                             error:NULL];

NSString *delimiter = @"\n";
NSArray *items = [content componentsSeparatedByString:delimiter];
NSString *character = @" ";
BOOL isContain = NO;
for (NSString *wordToBeSearched in items) {
isContain = ([string rangeOfString:wordToBeSearched].location != NSNotFound);
}
return isContain; 

}
```

You can go here for more [details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI)